# Сортировка в PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Вообщем через PDO кидаю такой запрос:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tasks` ORDER BY :order_db LIMIT :start_pos, :perpage");
$stmt->bindValue(':order_db', $order_db, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':start_pos', $start_pos, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':perpage', $perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$all_tasks = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $all_tasks[] = $row;
}
return $all_tasks;
```

Он работает с этим всё норм, но почему-то когда в `$order_db` передаешь другие данные по умолчанию туда ставится `login ASC`, даже если туда уйдет `login DESC` или `email DESC` то при выводе все равно сортировка получается по логину. Хелп.

Comment: Это происходит из-за того, что __нельзя байндить__ ни названия столбцов, ни названия таблиц в тексте подготовленного выражения. К тому же, следуя здравому смыслу, что вы ожидаете от подстановки "field DESC" вместо соответствующего плейсхолдера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался посмотрел и решил сделать так как на мой взгляд лучше не делать, но зато работает ))

```
if ($order_col == 'logina' || $order_col == 'emaila' || $order_col == 'statusa') {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tasks` ORDER BY " . $order_db . " ASC LIMIT :start_pos, :perpage");
} else {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tasks` ORDER BY " . $order_db . " DESC LIMIT :start_pos, :perpage");
}
$stmt->bindValue(':start_pos', $start_pos, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':perpage', $perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$all_tasks = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $all_tasks[] = $row;
}
return $all_tasks;
```